# Jenkins giving error : java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: demo.Main

Tags: java, jenkins

[Project structure .. click here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G2RuK.png)

```js
<dependencies>          
        <dependency>                
             <groupId>junit</groupId>                               
             <artifactId>junit</artifactId>                             
             <version>3.8.1</version>                               
             <scope>compile</scope>                             
        </dependency>
        <dependency>                
            <groupId>org.testng</groupId>                               
            <artifactId>testng</artifactId>                             
            <version>6.8</version>                              
            <scope>compile</scope>                                      
       </dependency>                
        <dependency>                
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>                              
            <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>                              
            <version>2.53.1</version>                               
        </dependency>               
       <dependency>
    <groupId>com.aventstack</groupId>
    <artifactId>extentreports</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.4</version>
</dependency>   
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.googlecode.json-simple</groupId>
    <artifactId>json-simple</artifactId>
    <version>1.1</version>
</dependency>           
   </dependencies>
   <properties>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
  </properties>
 <build>
<plugins>
<plugin>  
   <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>  
   <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>  
   <version>1.3</version>  
   <executions>  
    <execution>  
     <phase>test</phase>
     <goals>  
      <goal>java</goal>  
     </goals>   
    </execution>  
   </executions>
        <configuration>  
      <mainClass>demo.Main</mainClass>   
     </configuration>   
  </plugin>  
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.6.1</version>
        <configuration>
          <source>1.8</source>
          <target>1.8</target>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.19.1</version>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
</project>
```

I am new to Jenkins & have configured my project in it , while running it from eclipse project runs smoothly while executing the same from the jenkins giving me the below error , Also attaching the POM.xml . Please help

```html
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: demo.Main
 at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
 at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
 at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
 at org.codehaus.mojo.exec.ExecJavaMojo$1.run(ExecJavaMojo.java:281)
 at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 2.996 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2017-04-30T22:59:20+05:30
[INFO] Final Memory: 18M/172M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:1.3:java (default) on project demo: An exception occured while executing the Java class. demo.Main -> [Help 1]
```

Comment: Please provide your project directory tree listing.

Comment: Please find the required tree structure

Comment: That's the project layout, I was looking for the file navigation layout in eclipse, but let's  see what we can do with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My guess is that you are not using the standard maven directory layout, where `Main.class` should reside in `src/main/java/demo`

You can force maven to change your source directory like this

```
<sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
```

For more info on how the default POM looks like click [here](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-pom.html)

On a side note, I'd strongly recommend to :
 - standardize your code according to recommended maven layout
 - Not use eclipse. Try intelij (or netbeans, for a simpler maven integration )